# Downloading multiple files in background using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cloud, background-process

My question: what is the best way to know when the last image has been downloaded, since once all files have been downloaded I need to update the UI.

I am downloading an array of PFFiles from Parse. What I am doing the moment is: getting the array of PFFiles from parse this way

```
func getAllUserPictures(completion: (imageFiles: [PFFile]) -> Void) {
         guard let id = currentUserID else {
        return
    }

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Profile")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: id)
    query.includeKey("avatars")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { profile, error in
        guard let imageFiles = profile?.first?.objectForKey("avatars") as? [PFFile] else {
            return
        }
        completion(imageFiles: imageFiles)
    }
}
```

After having obtained the imageFile array from the completion handler I do proceed to download them this way:

```
func getUserPicturesWithBlock(completion: (result: [UIImage]) -> Void) {
    DataManager.sharedInstance.getAllUserPictures { imageFiles in
        for file in imageFiles {
            file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ data, error in
                guard let data = data, let image = UIImage (data: data) else{
                    return
                }

                self.imagesArray.append(image)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using multiple `PFImageView` from the `ParseUI` framework?

You could assign each of the PFFiles to a PFImageView in the completion of the query and then call `loadInBackground` on each PFImageView. The `PFImageView` class automatically handles updating the images once the data has been loaded and this would also update each image as soon as it's fetched rather than waiting for all of them together.

Alternatively, to keep a similar structure to what you already have, you could use the size of the imageFiles array to tell when they have all been loaded. In the completion of loading each file, you could check if the number of loaded images is equal to the total size of the array.

Comment: I have used the first method you suggest in another case when i had UIImageView in cells and they wold handle themselves, but in this case i have an UIScrollView where i add all the images after they have been downloaded. Already using the second method you have suggested but my concern is that one of the downloads might fail for some reason and the count of imageFiles and PFFiles wont be equal, preventing the UI to update.

Comment: Why not update the UI after each download? Refreshing the UI is a very efficient and quick task to do

Comment: Because i need to set the images in the scroll view just once in order to prevent "white pages" while the user is scrolling. I would prefer for the user to wait until all the downloading is done rather then showing not a full view in this case. The download is done in a couple of seconds, the problem is i need something like a completion handler that would notify when all the images have been downloaded including the cases where there are failed downloads.

Comment: Does the ordering matter? If the order is irrelevant, then you could only add the completed images to the UI and refresh/add the new images as they come in.

Comment: Yes the ordering is imperative in this case!

Comment: In that case I think you'll have to use the second method we mentioned where you compare the number of loaded images against the total size of the array. To handle the situations where one of the loads could fail, in the error completion block remove the failed image from the array so it does not affect the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Should have thought about removing them from the array in the fail block earlier. That's a nice way to handle it for the moment. Upvoting your answer but still not making it the accepted answer.